# Astrodynamics Patched Conic Approximation

Tags: coordinate-systems, orbital-motion, astronomy, celestial-mechanics

I would need some help as I don’t know how to find $p$ and $e$ of an heliocentric orbit in order to calculate the following formula.

[image]

Comment: What _specifically_ is giving you trouble? Saying "_I don't know how_" is too vague. Please edit your question accordingly so that whatever conceptual problem you are having is clarified, and therefore more likely to be answered. Thanks.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the text says just before eq (8.3-4) "once p and e of the ... orbit have been selected." The use of p and e is probably from *Principles of Astronautics* by M. Vertregt (either edition, 2nd edition 1965, p. 234) shows all elliptical orbits are confined to the triangle on the (p,e) plane of e<1 (the parabola limit), p=n(1-e) and p=1+e to be tangent to the outer orbit or the inner orbit. The ratio of outer to inner orbit radii in n.

The pages included with the post are from the first edition of *Fundamentals of Astrodynamics* by Bate *et al* (page 306 of 2nd edition).

Comment: Would you know how I can find a free online copy of this? For the rest thank you very much this has been very useful.